# Adding integers to MONTH (XX) affecting logic of CASE WHEN statement, how to go around it?

Tags: sql, datetime, teradata, case-when

Looking to get Order ID counts per month (after user signs up for a subscription service). I'm using a CASE WHEN statement where I'm taking the transaction date, then equating that to the subscription month and adding integers for each line to get Month 0, Month 1, Month 2, etc.

Ideally looking to create a concatenated year+month column to Group By so only one query is needed to get the trickle-down order value of user cohorts months 0 through 6 post enrollment. But this first draft isn't working.

Due to some Logic errors (I believe), adding integers to the month(date) function is not being read correctly, so I'm ending up with a ton of zero's after month 0.

I have checked that there indeed is rows that aren't being pulled, when I set the month (date) condition = to a certain interger ie :

```
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = 2 then order_id end) as month_1
```

then the code works, so this must be due to logic with adding integers to months.

```
select 
count(user_uuid),
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = month (first_subscription_date) then order_id end) as month_0,
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = (month (first_subscription_date) + 1) then order_id end) as month_1,
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = (month (first_subscription_date) + 2) then order_id end) as month_2,
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = (month (first_subscription_date) + 3) then order_id end) as month_3,
 count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = (month (first_subscription_date) + 4) then order_id end) as month_4,
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = (month (first_subscription_date) + 5) then order_id end) as month_5,
count(distinct case when month(transaction_date) = (month (first_subscription_date) + 6) then order_id end) as month_6
from sandbox.select_hbw_orders
where first_subscription_date between '2018-12-01' and '2018-12-31'
and pre_or_post_subscription = 'post'
```

Current results:

```
Count(user_uuid)    month_0 month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 
          34,899    11,894  0   0   0   0   0
```

Expected results:

```
Count(user_uuid)    month_0 month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 
          34,89      11,894 4,009   3,274   3,462   3,107   3,406
```

What's wrong with my logic? I'm certainly able to use filters to limit the subscription month/year, but i'm going to pull about 12 months worth of data, so I want to keep things efficient with a case when statement.

Comment: Sample data where your query isn't working would be very helpful.

Comment: Sample data is provided under "current results" 

Count(user_uuid)    month_0 month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 
          34,899    11,894  0   0   0   0   0   

then expected results (with the query that is working): 
Count(user_uuid)    month_0 month_1 month_2 month_3 month_4 month_5 
          34,89      11,894 4,009   3,274   3,462   3,107   3,406

Comment: Subscription date of 2018-12, will return 12 for month(subscription_date), so obviously 12+1 =13, and there is no month 13

Comment: No, sample raw data, not output.

Comment: I think you want to be using [months_between](https://docs.teradata.com/reader/1DcoER_KpnGTfgPinRAFUw/zK_N0ad75D2uAcum1jfuMw) - `when months_between(first_subscription_date,transaction_date) = 1...`.

Comment: got it! Thank you patrick, i didn't think that the logic wouldn't apply between years that make total sense!

Comment: I will try months_between Andrew! Thank you